# How to use awk for a variable in UNIX script

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I would like to use awk for a variable
that has the form abc,def
I also don't know how to use awk for a variable instead of a file
I tried the following but it doesn't works

`awk -F, '{$1" "$2}' $var`
and
`awk -F, '{$1" "$2}' "$var"`

Comment: What do you want to do with the variable? `awk` may not be the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a herestring

```
awk 'commands' <<< "$string"
```

Also if you want to print the first two fields of a comma separated string, change the command to

```
awk -F, '{print $1, $2}' <<< "$string"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
echo "$variable" | awk -F, '{print $1 " " $2}'
```